# Net::HTTP doesn't start downloading file after post request

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am trying to make POST request with `Net::HTTP` to specific website, and start downloading file after response is returned.
I tested this first with wget, and it worked fine.I also tried with `httpi` and `unirest` gems and it went fine . However, because `Net::HTTP` is low-level API and I need more control(for example, tracking downloading progress), I'll stick with it.
The problem is, downloading just won't start.So here's the code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'tempfile'
uri = URI.parse("http://mywebsite.com")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data({'filed' => 'data'})


response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req) do |response|
   temp_file = Tempfile.new("new_file")
   response.read_body do |chunk|
        temp_file << chunk
   end

 end
}
```

I figured that the problem must be in response, what I get is not `Net::HTTPOK`
but `HTTPSeeOther` and here's more info about it

```
      #<Net::HTTPSeeOther:0x91f2670>
            {"server"=>["nginx"], "date"=>["Sat, 21 Dec 2013 22:32:14 GMT"], 
        "content-type"=>["text/html"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], 
            "connection"=>["keep-alive"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], 
            "cache-control"=>["no-cache, must-revalidate"], 
    "expires"=>["Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"], 
"location"=>["http://mywebsite.com/path/to/file.rar"]}
```

The other 2 gems I mentioned knew how to start download automatically and I don't know what to do with HTTPSeeOther .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're getting a redirect response from the server, which `wget`, `curl`, and high-level libraries will follow automatically. With `Net::HTTP`, you'll need to start a new `GET` request to that location.